# How to write a constant function reference

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

At the moment I have a class defined similar to this:

```
class dummy{
    public:
        dummy(void(&func)(int))
            : member{func}{}

        void(&member)(int);
};
```

but I want to have `member` defined as a `const` function reference. I'm not sure exactly how to write this or if it is even possible.

P.S. PLEASE don't recommend me `std::function` I'm not oblivious to it's existence and have no objection to it, I just want to know whether something like this is doable.

Comment: [dcl.fct]/6 "The effect of a *cv-qualifier-seq* in a function declarator is not the same as adding cv-qualification on top
of the function type. In the latter case, the cv-qualifiers are ignored. [*Note:* a function type that has a
*cv-qualifier-seq* is not a cv-qualified type; there are no cv-qualified function types. — *end note*]"

Comment: To do a typedef I think I would need the answer to my question first, which I think is that there isn't such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The syntax:**

Syntactically, you can achieve this through a type alias (or `typedef`):

```
using function_t = void(int); // or typedef void (function_t)(int);

class dummy {
public:
    const function_t& member;
    dummy(const function_t& func)
         : member{func}{}

};
```

**The semantics:**

However, the "correct syntax" doesn't buy you anything: `dummy` is the same as

```
class dummy {
public:
    function_t& member;
    dummy(function_t& func)
         : member{func}{}

};
```

(which, in turn is the same as the OP's definition) because the `const` qualifiers are ignored as per C++11 8.3.5/6:

> > The effect of a cv-qualifier-seq in a function declarator is not the same as adding cv-qualification on top of the function type. **In the latter case, the cv-qualifiers are ignored**. [ Note: a function type that has a cv-qualifier-seq is not a cv-qualified type; **there are no cv-qualified function types**. —end note ]

**What about rvalues?**

As far as I undestand (from a comment to [user657267](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657267/user657267)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22952659/1137388)) the motivation for taking the argument as reference to `const` was to enable passing rvalues (temporaries):

```
void f(int) { }

function_t make_function() { return f; }

dummy d1(f);
dummy d2(make_function());
```

However, this doesn't compile, not because of `dummy`, but because `make_function` returns a function which is forbiden by C++11 8.3.5/8

> > If the type of a parameter includes a type of the form “pointer to array of unknown bound of `T`” or “reference to array of unknown bound of `T`,” the program is ill-formed.<sup>99</sup> **Functions shall not have a return type of type array or function**, although they may have a return type of type pointer or reference to such things. There shall be no arrays of functions, although there can be arrays of pointers to functions.

A natural "solution" would be returning a reference:

```
function& make_function() { return f; }
```

or

```
function&& make_function() { return f; }
```

In both cases, the type of the expression `make_function()` is an lvalue (which defies the purpose of `dummy` using reference to `const` to enable passing rvalues) as per C++11 5.2.2/10

> > **A function call is an lvalue if the result type is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type**, an xvalue if the result type is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise.

Actually, value category is not an issue here. With any legal declaration of `make_function` and any definition of `dummy` seem above the declarations of `d1` and `d2` work fine.

Nevertheless, the mentioned comment to [user657267](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657267/user657267)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22952659/1137388) talks about passing a lambda but a reference to function cannot bind to lambda expression because it has a different type:

```
dummy d3([](int){}); // Error!
```

**The suggested solution**

Instead of references use pointers:

```
using function_t = void(int); // or typedef void (function_t)(int);

class dummy {
public:
    function_t* member;
    dummy(function_t* func)
         : member{func}{}

};

void f(int) { }

function_t& make_function() { return f; }

dummy d1(f);               // OK
dummy d2(make_function()); // OK
dummy d3([](int){});       // OK
```

Final remarks:

1. Again, declaring `const function_t* member` and `dummy(const function_t* func)` doesn't buy you anything because, as per references, the `const` qualifiers are ignored.
2. The initialization of `d1` and `d2` work because functions are implicitly converted to pointer to functions (see C++ 4.3/1).
3. If a function argument is of function type, the compiler changes its type to a pointer to function. Hence, `dummy`'s constructor can be declared as `dummy(function_t func);`.
4. The initialization of `d3` works because captureless lambdas are implicitly converted to pointer to functions. It wouldn't work for lambdas with captures.